# What is the UIButton backgroundImage key? iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, image, uibutton, setvalue

this is my first question.

I am trying to programmatically change the background image of a `UIButton` but there is a problem, I can't find the key of the background image. 
To understand, this is my code:

```
    [[self.view viewWithTag:69000+i] setValue:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d-options.png", i+1]] forKey:@"backgroundImage"];
```

When this is executed, the app crashes. Giving this error:

**Thread 1: signal SIGTRAP** in main.m
 and in the debugger: **(lldb)**

So, in case I am right and the crash is caused by the incorrect key (*backgroundImage*), what is the key that refers to background image?

Thank you very much!!

PD: I need this done by self.view viewWithTag......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And why don't you use this :

```
   if([[self.view viewWithTag:69000+i] isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
    {
        UIButton *currentButton = (UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:69000+i];
        [currentButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d-options.png", i+1]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
```

Comment: +1 I wanted backgroundImage so I corrected it and it worked!I didnt know isKindOfClass method. Although what key was the right one to change the background image by my way? Thank you!

Comment: You can't set it by assigning it to a key.  It is not a dictionary.  You can only use `setImage:forState:` and `setBackgroundImage:forState:` to set the `image` and `backgroundImage` properties of the `UIButton`.